# How to restrict ios sandbox access from .app file (Migrating an App to a Sandbox)

Tags: ios, encryption, restriction, .app

I am able to see the source code from my .app file that is i am able access image 
files. How can i restrict that? I dont want my user to access the files from app. Please help me in resolving this issue.

Update: Sorry i was supposed to write .h/.m files are not accessed but image files can.. 
There is a mismatch in type , i didn't observe

Comment: How can u do that ? when u build the target it .ipa file that matters.. How you are actually able to see .h/.m files ?

Comment: this should not happen. did you accidentally add your source code file  to Targets=>Build Phases as "Copy Bundle Resources" or "Copy File"?

Comment: You can open .ipa file using zip utilities but can't see any code but yes you can see images, audio files, video files, certificates etc. but can't access code of that .ipa

Comment: Sorry i was supposed to write .h/.m files are not accessed but image files can.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot see code from the IPA you upload to the store. No one can see your code. Someone *could*, however, see you image files, audio files, sqlite files, plist files, etc.

**Per your update:**

You cannot prevent the files from being accessed. It's like the web: if you can see it, you can steal it.

Comment: +I don't even need a jailbreak -- and also sure one can see code. disassembler